# What is a reverse mortgage?

Tags: mortgage, terminology, reverse-mortgages

What is a reverse mortgage? I hear these advertise often but don't understand how they are different from a regular mortgage! Can somebody explain please what they are and when they would be useful? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Reverse Mortgage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse%5FMortgage) from Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia:

> A reverse mortgage (or lifetime
>   mortgage) is a loan available to
>   seniors, and is used to release the
>   home equity in the property as one
>   lump sum or multiple payments. The
>   homeowner's obligation to repay the
>   loan is deferred until the owner dies,
>   the home is sold, or the owner leaves
>   (e.g., into aged care).
>
> In a conventional mortgage the
>   homeowner makes a monthly amortized
>   payment to the lender; after each
>   payment the equity increases within
>   his or her property, and typically
>   after the end of the term (e.g., 30
>   years) the mortgage has been paid in
>   full and the property is released from
>   the lender. In a reverse mortgage, the
>   home owner makes no payments and all
>   interest is added to the lien on the
>   property. If the owner receives
>   monthly payments, or a bulk payment of
>   the available equity percentage for
>   their age, then the debt on the
>   property increases each month.

Answer (score 8):

In a reverse mortgage, you sell your house one month at a time.  It's a good option if you need the income, and don't care to leave your house as an inheritance as part of your estate.